# Logstash not forwarding logs to ES via Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, elastic-stack

I'm using ELK 5.0.1 and Kafka 0.10.1.0 . I'm not sure why my logs aren't forwarding I installed Kafkacat and was successfully able to Produce and Consume logs from all the 3 servers where Kafka cluster is installed.

shipper.conf

```
input {
    file {
            start_position => "beginning"
            path => "/var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log"
            }
}

 output {
 kafka {
    topic_id => "stash"
    bootstrap_servers  => "<i.p1>:9092,<i.p2>:9092,<i.p3>:9092"
  }
}
```

receiver.conf

```
input {
kafka {
        topics => ["stash"]
        group_id => "stashlogs"
        bootstrap_servers  => "<i.p1>:2181,<i,p2>:2181,<i.p3>:2181"

}
}

 output {
    elasticsearch {
       hosts => ["<eip>:9200","<eip>:9200","<eip>:9200"]
       manage_template => false
       index => "logstash-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
  }
 }
```

Logs: Getting the below warnings in logstash-plain.log

```
[2017-04-17T16:34:28,238][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.common.protocol.Errors] Unexpected error 
code: 38.
[2017-04-17T16:34:28,238][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient] Error while fetching 
metadata with correlation id 44 : {stash=UNKNOWN}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your bootstrap servers are using zookeeper ports. Try using Kafka ports (default 9092)

Comment: thanks for this, major oversight on my part. i fixed it but its still not working. I don't see any error. I have 6.2.7 as logstash-input-kafka for Kafka version : 0.10.1.1 ELK is at 5.0.1 . Not really sure what else to do.

Comment: Hmm maybe bump up the log level to debug. Not sure if it's a Kafka problem but if you fail connecting to Kafka sometimes you need debug to see why.

Comment: With logstash-input-kafka 5.1.1 and bumping LS to 5.1.1 i get the below error. I shutdown kafka and zookeeper and deleted all the consumer offsets and restarted and i still get this error. When i bump my input plugin to 6.2.7 , i dont see any errors but nothing happens. really strange.

03:28:22.619 [Ruby-0-Thread-6: /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-input-kafka-5.1.1/lib/logstash/inputs/kafka.rb:225] DEBUG org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator - Cannot auto-commit offsets for group aupm since the coordinator is unknown

Comment: Ah ok, coordinator is unknown implies we're having trouble getting in contact with the right broker that's acting coordinator for the group. If you run the console consumer with this group id does it work? Trying to narrow in on if this is a Kafka problem or a client problem.

Comment: yep, so i ran the console consumer and subsribed to the topic "stash" and saw all the messages being read realtime. I tested on all servers that form the Kafka cluster and all of them can read the message.

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks for your help. the debugging helped a lot. Turns out that i did not have the SG rules for Ingress open from ELK servers on port 9092. As soon as i did that, logs started flowing in.